# Empty Swagger UI page on OpenAPI generator plugin 6.x config in Java Spring

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springdoc, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I recently updated the openapi-generator-plugin and saw that there is a parameter "*useSwaggerUI*" documented   "*Open the OpenApi specification in swagger-ui. Will also import and configure needed dependencies*". When i turn this on a Homecontroller is being generated which redirects to a swagger-ui.html, however i see a blank white page.

My question is, do i need to configure more or can the plugin generate the whole swagger ui for me ?